# Python Regex that adds space after dot

Tags: python, regex

How can I use `re` to write a regex in Python that finds the pattern:

> dot "." followed directly by any char [a-zA-Z] (not space or digit)

and then add a space between the dot and the char?

i.e.

```
str="Thanks.Bob"
newsttr="Thanks. Bob"
```

Thanks in advance,
Zvi

Answer (score 16):

`re.sub(r'\.([a-zA-Z])', r'. \1', oldstr)`

Comment: @Chris I know. I used it because he already assigned to it in his question. I fixed it now.

Comment: ARG! Mixed case in a variable name!

Comment: ARG! Approximately nothing left to complain of! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

```
re.sub('(?<=\.)(?=[a-zA-Z])', ' ', str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
re.sub(r"\.([a-zA-Z])", ". \\1", "Thanks.Bob")
```