# Python Regex to add space after dot or comma

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as follows:

line = "This is a text.This is another text,it has no space after the comma."

I want to add a space after dots **and** commas, so that the end result is:

newline = "This is a text. This is another text, it has no space after the comma."

I tried the solution from here: [Python Regex that adds space after dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455557/python-regex-that-adds-space-after-dot/), but it does work only for dots **or** commas. I have not been able to grasp how to get the regex recognize both characters at once.

Comment: As a simple solution since you're not comfortable with regex, why not do two passes? One for handling periods and one for handling commas.

Comment: you can also do it without regex

Answer (score 33):

Use this regex to match locations where preceding character is a **dot or a comma** and the next character isn't a space:

```
(?<=[.,])(?=[^\s])
```

- `(?<=[.,])` positive lookbehind that looks for **dots** or **commas**
- `(?=[^\s])` positive lookahead that matches anything that *isn't a space*

So this will match positions just after the comma or the space like `ext.This` or `text,it`. but not `word. This`.

Replace with a single space ()

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N0s8qV/1/)

Python:

```
line = "This is a text.This is another text,it has no space after the comma."
re.sub(r'(?<=[.,])(?=[^\s])', r' ', line)

// Output: 'This is a text. This is another text, it has no space after the comma.'
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Regular expressions maybe scaring, but they are compact and fast.

Comment: Yes, once you get a hang of it, you'll realize they're _really_ simple and efficient and not that scary. I'd recommend starting [here](https://www.rexegg.com/) and using regex101 to play around as you learn!

Comment: what if the sentence contains decimal values ?

Comment: @degant, why we need r' ' in re.sub()?

Comment: @user15479632 Because the character "\" has specific meaning in python. Here we are using \s which identified as anomalous. Using raw string overcomes this issue.

Comment: This will not work when you have a decimal number in the sentence. It will add a space for the number too.

Answer (score 3):

alternatively your can also be solved without regex as follow :

```
>>> line = "This is a text.This is another text,it has no space after the comma."
>>> line.replace('.', '. ', line.count('.')).replace(',', ', ', line.count(','))
'This is a text. This is another text, it has no space after the comma. '
>>>
```